# Unbalanced call to dispatch_group_leave() in duplicated for loop

Tags: ios, concurrency, dispatch

I am using dispatch group to get a data string. Here is a code and I am not sure why I get `Unbalanced call to dispatch_group_leave()` in this code.

```
var queue = DispatchQueue(label: "extractStringQueue", attributes: .concurrent)
queue.async {
  let m_group = DispatchGroup() 
    let weeks = self.weekDataArray 

    for week in weeks {
        for day in week.dayDataArray {
             m_group.enter()
             day.processStringData(dataName, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in 
                    if true {
                        // Process 
                        m_group.leave()    
                    }
              })
        }
    }

    m_group.notify(queue: queue, execute: {
     // CompletionHandler
    })
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Two possible issues :

**Issue 1:**

`processStringData` function might be calling its `completionHandler` more than once hence resulting in multiple `m_group.leave()` call. Number of `m_group.leave()` should always be equal to `m_group.enter()`. If you try to `m_group.leave()` more number of times then u entered the group u'll receive this error.

**Issue 2:**

```
    m_group.enter()
    day.processStringData(dataName, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in 
    if true {
       // Process 
       m_group.leave()    
    }
})
```

Your code says only if completionHandler returns true leave the group so if it returns false u'll never leave the group. This will cause `m_group.notify` never to trigger even if once the completion block returns false and unnecessarily blocks the thread forever.

What u should do rather is

```
    m_group.enter()
    day.processStringData(dataName, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) in 
    if true {
       // Process    
    }
    m_group.leave() 
})
```

**Issue 3:**

Make sure processStringData is not changing the thread before executing the completion block. Its a common practice to switch back to main thread and execute the completion block. Entering to `dispatch_group` using different thread and trying to leave the group from completely different thread will also cause unbalanced call to leave.

Comment: Interesting  Very well explain , But I couldn't get your third point , He has already did queue. async  still it is relevant ,Could you pls explain more if you know

Comment: @mike-alter : Am not really sure though :) Its usually a practice to switch to main thread before executing the completion block passed as a function parameter. Like alamofire, AFNetworking in all these third party frameworks though actual network call happens on background thread before returning the server response with completion block passed as argument to their calls they do a thread switch. All they do is enclose completion() call inside DispatchQueue.main.async { completion() }. This will cause thread switch because Dispatch groups internally use semaphores switching threads like this

Comment: might leave the enter and leave call unbalanced. Just a guess

Comment: @mike-alter : Thank u :)